# How do I useContext hook on React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner and I'm currently developing an application using a React Template. The template uses React Router v6 for the router with `use Routes()` hook.
Every route of the application is protected and can be only accessed by logging in

I'm planning to implement login using `use Context()` hook but I cant seem to figure out how to wrap the routes in the Provider tag.

My two doubts are:

1. How do I wrap my routes in the `<Context Provider>` tag
2. Should I wrap all my routes in an application like this.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you will need the Context. I always prefer to write a hook:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    login: () => {},
    logout: () => {}
});

export function AuthProvider({ children }){

    const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    const login = () => {
        setAuthenticated(true);
    }
    const logout = () => {
        setAuthenticated(false);
    }
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated, login: login, logout: logout}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default function AuthConsumer() {
    return useContext(AuthContext); 
}
```

Then you will need a private route component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import useAuth from "./useAuth";

function RequireAuth({ children, redirectTo }) {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
    return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}

export default RequireAuth;
```

Finally you will mix in your routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import RequireAuth from './components/PrivateRoute';
import useAuth from "./components/useAuth";

const Home = () => <div><h1>Welcome home</h1></div>
const Dashboard = () => <h1>Dashboard (Private)</h1>;

function App() {

  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={
              <RequireAuth redirectTo="/login">
                <Dashboard />
              </RequireAuth>
            }>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to={isAuthenticated ? '/dashboard' : '/'} />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I hope this will help.